# datagrid view combobox item selection vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I have a datagridview which I have furnished using the following code...
The trouble I have though is with the combobox column.

First off how can I have a preset value already selected in the combobox.

Secondly When I run my code I have to click the combobox's twice how can I change this to only having to click them once?

```
'CREATE DATAGRIVIEW 1 COLUMN LAYOUT...S
    DataGridView1.ColumnCount = 8
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "QTY"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "H"
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "L"
    DataGridView1.Columns(3).Name = "W"
    DataGridView1.Columns(4).Name = "ANG 1"
    DataGridView1.Columns(5).Name = "ANG 2"
    DataGridView1.Columns(6).Name = "MAT"
    DataGridView1.Columns(7).Name = "THK"

    Dim ComboBoxColumn As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    ComboBoxColumn.HeaderText = "TYPE"
    ComboBoxColumn.Name = "ComboBoxColumn"
    ComboBoxColumn.MaxDropDownItems = 5
    ComboBoxColumn.Items.Add("NON")
    ComboBoxColumn.Items.Add("SNG")
    ComboBoxColumn.Items.Add("PER")
    ComboBoxColumn.Items.Add("PAR")
    ComboBoxColumn.Items.Add("AXS")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(8, ComboBoxColumn)

    Dim checkBoxColumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
    checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = "IDW"
    checkBoxColumn.Name = "checkBoxColumn"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(9, checkBoxColumn)
    'CREATE DATAGRIVIEW 1 COLUMN LAYOUT...E
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean a defaultvalue for the combobox:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting

    If (e.ColumnIndex = 8) Then ' your combo column index 
        e.Value = "PER"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The selection in the combo box reflects the `Value` of the cell.  If you want something to be selected then you have to set the `Value` of the cell accordingly.

Your second issue, which is unrelated and should therefore have been asked in an unrelated post, is as a result of the `EditMode` of the grid.  Change that to the appropriate value for the behaviour you want.